# 64bit equivalent class for a wmi class "win32reg_addremoveprograms"?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, wmi

My code below works perfectly on a 32-bit Windows machine, however it refuses to work on a 64-bit machine due to the 32-bit WMI class `win32reg_addremoveprograms` used in the code. Is there a 64-bit equivalent of this class?

```
$ServerFile = "D:\SharePoint\Powershell\AddRemovePrograms\Machines.txt"
$ServerList = Get-Content $ServerFile

$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Excel.displayalerts=$False
$Excel.visible = $True

$workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$workbook.workSheets.item(2).delete()
$workbook.WorkSheets.item(2).delete()

$Sheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1)
$Sheet.Name= "Program List";

$intRow = 1

foreach ($NextServer in $ServerList)
{
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = “Computer Name”
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $NextServer

    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.ColorIndex = 11
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.ColorIndex = 11
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.Bold = $True

    $intRow = $intRow + 2
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Programs"
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.ColorIndex = 8
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
    $intRow = $intRow + 1

    $colItems =get-wmiobject -class "win32reg_addremoveprograms" -computername $NextServer  |  select-object -property DisplayName | sort-object  DisplayName

    foreach ($objItem in $colItems)
    {
        if ($objItem.DisplayName.IndexOf('Update') -eq -1 -and $objItem.DisplayName.IndexOf('2007 Microsoft Office') -eq -1)
        {   
            $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = $objItem.DisplayName
            $intRow = $intRow + 1
        }
    }
    $intRow = $intRow + 2
}

$workArea = $Sheet.UsedRange
$workArea.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$workbook.SaveAs("D:\SharePoint\Powershell\AddRemovePrograms\Programs.xls")
$workbook.close() 
$a = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workArea)
$a = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Sheet)
$a = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$Excel.Quit()
$a = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
Remove-Variable Excel, intRow ,workbook, Sheet,colItems, ServerFile, ServerList, a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the [SCCM/SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Systems_Management_Server) client installed on your 64-bit machine? Because the `Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms` WMI class is added by the SCCM/SMS client, and therefore isn't available if you don't have it installed.

Note also that `Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms` provide info on 32-bit installed applications only. To get info on 64-bit applications, use the `Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms64` class (available in SMS 2003 SP3 and later).