# Powershell Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms getting date output

Tags: date, powershell, output

How can I get the `InstallDate` from `Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms` to display by day/month/year?

This is the command I need to use

> get-wmiobject -Class Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms -ComputerName
>   AComputer| where {$_.DisplayName -notlike "*hotfix*" -and
>   $_.DisplayName -notlike "*Security Update*" -and  $_.DisplayName
>   -notlike "*Update for Windows *"} | select DisplayName,Version,Publisher,InstallDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the InstallDate looks like the InstallDate of the Win32_Product class (e.g 20131209):

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('20131209','yyyyMMdd',$null).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks Shay for that. As I see from another reply this will not get information back from 64 bit installed software. So I guess I will need to obtain this information from the registry if that is a quicker method than using Win32_Product.

Comment: In any case, as far as I know, the date value is in the same format.

Answer (score 2):

just to let you know the Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms  class is not a common class, it is added by the SMS/SCCM. It also only shows info related to 32-bit programs. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2417452/3065397)
 For that reason I do not have the class available on the station and cannot provide you with the exact steps . Please provide output of this commands:

```
$item = $gwmi Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms | select -first 1
$item.InstallDate
$item.InstallDate.GetType().fullname
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact it won't get info back from 64bit programs.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to format the date like the example below.

```
$date=Get-Date
```

Monday, December 9, 2013 5:29:50 AM

```
$date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

09/12/2013

**EDIT:**
I don't have access to Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms, so not tested.
try adding this to the end:

```
   | %{ $_.InstallDate = ($_.InstallDate.tostring("dd/MM/yyyy") ); $_ }
```

So the final: (added ` for line breaks)

```
get-wmiobject -Class Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms -ComputerName AComputer| `  
where {$_.DisplayName -notlike "hotfix" -and $_.DisplayName -notlike "Security Update" -and $_.DisplayName -notlike "*Update for Windows *"} | `  
select DisplayName,Version,Publisher,InstallDate | `  
%{ $_.InstallDate = ($_.InstallDate.tostring("dd/MM/yyyy") ); $_ }
```

Or if it is in the date format like Shay mentioned,

```
| %{ $_.InstallDate = ([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate,'yyyyMMdd',$null).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')) ;$_}
```

Full script:

```
get-wmiobject -Class Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms -ComputerName AComputer| `  
where {$_.DisplayName -notlike "hotfix" -and $_.DisplayName -notlike "Security Update" -and $_.DisplayName -notlike "*Update for Windows *"} | `  
select DisplayName,Version,Publisher,InstallDate | `  
%{ $_.InstallDate = ([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate,'yyyyMMdd',$null).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')) ;$_}
```